# Star Trek TOS without modern CG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Is there any way of seeing the original Star Treks without the modern computer graphics? Sure, it's nice they've gone to the effort to dress it up by modernizing some of the cheesier effects, but what if I want to see just how cheesy those original effects were, one more time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping questions are off-topic

Comment: It is truly pedantic to close this question as off-topic.   It's a very reasonable question about what versions of an SF work are available where.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_The_Original_Series#Home_video_release) you can pick up the Blu-rays, which let you choose if you want the new effects or the original effects.  Alternatively, if you can find them, you can pick up the [first DVD release](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002I831S) of the series, as this was prior to the remastering.

Comment: i assumed that any DVDs currently available would be the remastered ones. will have to figure out how to tell them apart.

Comment: @JustJeff Take a look at the 'first DVD release' link.  That's what the first DVDs look like.  The new ones have a clear 'Remastered Edition' label that you can see by clicking the link under 'Other Formats & Versions'.

Comment: I can attest to being able to see the original on Blu-ray.

Comment: @JustJeff: “i assumed that any DVDs currently available would be the remastered ones” — thankfully, Lucas is the exception, rather than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative idea, search on your favourite auction type site and/or charity type shops for VHS tapes . They do exist for *The Original Series*.

I do not know how easily you will be able to get them though (does not seem to be any shortage of them in the U.K. at least) and if you would want them on this type of media either , assuming you still have or can obtain a player, over here the VCR seems a rare sight now in people's homes.

There might then with imported tapes be a issue with format aka NTSC vs PAL, I do not have the recollection of how much an issue that may be other than a memory that they tend to work possibly in monochrome but a modern player well say not a 80's relic one over here usually would cope with NTSC from what I can just about remember.

I guess all I am saying with the last paragraph above is YMMV if you went this route with imported media as not sure where you are in the world. On a positive ending note at least there is none of this region restrictions nonsense.